# In Emacs, how to use `<tab>` to call `vimish-fold-unfold`?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, folding

I'd like to be able to use `<tab>` to unfold folded text when using `vimish-fold`, how could I do that without override the default binding of `<tab>`?